# Word 2007 opens document read-only using iT Hit Ajax Library

Tags: word-2007, ithit-webdav-server

We have implemented the iT Hit server (v3.9) and Ajax library (v1.8.0.1342) and everything is fine with Word 2010 and 2013 and even Office for Mac:2011 but Word 2007 opens the document as read-only...we have tried using the information at http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/ms_office_read_only.  We are using WebDAV.Client.DocManager.EditDocument(sFilename, "/ITHitMountOpenDocument.jar"); to open the document from a link on a web page.  With 2007, there is not LOCK commands in the IIS log or in Fiddler...With 2010 and 2013, the LOCK command is in both...Also tried Webfldrs-KB907306-ENU.exe and updating the MSDAIPP.dll file. The client PC configuration is Windows 7 Professional SP1 (32bit), IE11 and Word 2007 (12.0.6715.5000) SP3 MSO (12.0.6683.5000).

Answer (score 0):

The most typical cause of read-only issue with Microsoft Office 2007 is WebDAV server does not process requests on website root.

> Microsoft Office 2007 and earlier may submit OPTIONS and PROPFIND
>   requests to site root (http://server/) and requires the server to
>   respond properly. If your WebDAV server is non-root (for example
>   http://server/dav/) Microsoft Office 2007 may open documents as
>   read-only.

If you are adding WebDAV to your project using ['Add WebDAV Server Implementation' wizard](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/documentation/vs_wizards) you will find the following code in your web.config file added by the wizard:

```
<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
      <add verb="OPTIONS,PROPFIND" path="*" type="WebApplication1.WebDAVServerImpl.DavHandler" name="My WebDAV Handler Root" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

This enables WebDAV requests processing on site root in addition to your WebDAV folder (by default located in /DAV/ folder).

You can use Fiddler or any other HTTP debugging proxy to capture the request and see if there are any failed requests sent to site root.

---

**EDIT:** *How to configure WebDAV server on root*

As soon as WebDAV server is to large extent is a regular ASP.NET application, the configuration process is no different from configuring an ASP.NET web site on site root.

In short: Go to *Sites* node in IIS Manager and select *Add Website* in context menu. Fill-in the *Site name* in the *Add Website* dialog and select the application pool. In the *Physical path* field provide the path to the folder where your web.config file is located. Specify Binding options, such as hostname and port if necessary. Click OK.

You can find detailed instractions about how to configure WebDAV samples in [WebDAV Server Examples](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples) section. The specifics of IIS configuration could be found in [How to Configure Your WebDAV Server in IIS](http://www.webdavsystem.com/server/server_examples/iis) article.

Comment: the handlers section is in the web.config file for the site...I'm not sure what is meant by non-root...I have tried a site under the default (http:<server>/tms) and one not under default (http:<server>:8086/ in IIS...I ran fiddler and there are http options with 401.2 results but I'm not sure how to authorize them...the site is using basic authentication...

Comment: The IIS Log contains...1 of 2
2015-02-25 15:21:47 W3SVC1857427687 8.20.78.17 OPTIONS / - 8086 - 75.151.144.117 DavClnt 401 2 2148074254
2015-02-25 15:22:02 W3SVC1857427687 8.20.78.17 OPTIONS / - 8086 - 75.151.144.117 DavClnt 401 2 2148074254
2015-02-25 15:22:11 W3SVC1857427687 8.20.78.17 OPTIONS /Edit_WebDAV - 8086 - 75.151.144.117 Microsoft-WebDAV-MiniRedir/6.1.7601 401 2 2148074254

Comment: IIS Log 2 of 3 actually
2015-02-25 15:22:11 W3SVC1857427687 8.20.78.17 GET /Edit_WebDAV/AD-WI-0001.doc - 8086 - 75.151.144.117 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+InfoPath.2;+.NET4.0E;+MSOffice+12) 401 2 2148074254

Comment: IIS log 3 of 3
2015-02-25 15:22:30 W3SVC1857427687 8.20.78.17 GET /Edit_WebDAV/AD-WI-0001.doc - 8086 tmsadmin 75.151.144.117 Mozilla/4.0+(compatible;+MSIE+7.0;+Windows+NT+6.1;+Trident/7.0;+SLCC2;+.NET+CLR+2.0.50727;+.NET+CLR+3.5.30729;+.NET+CLR+3.0.30729;+Media+Center+PC+6.0;+.NET4.0C;+InfoPath.2;+.NET4.0E;+MSOffice+12) 304 0 0
2015-02-25 15:22:30 W3SVC1857427687 8.20.78.17 HEAD /Edit_WebDAV/AD-WI-0001.doc - 8086 tmsadmin 75.151.144.117 Microsoft+Office+Existence+Discovery 200 0 0

Comment: As far as I see from your log your server does not process at least OPTIONS WebDAV requests on site root "/". It replies with 401 response, while it should provide a valid WebDAV response. Probably your WebDAV server is configured on /Edit_WebDAV/ folder. This is probably the reason why your server does not work with MS Office 2007. MS Office 2007 does not support non-root WebDAV configuration.